# Does this sentence' That is so incredulous' make sense?

Tags: grammar

Does this sentence make sense?
That is so incredulous, I am not sure.

Answer (score 1):

You have the wrong usage for **incredulous** which is applied to people.

The [Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/incredulous) has

> **incredulous**
>   ADJECTIVE
>   (of a person or their manner) unwilling or unable to believe something.
>   *Journalists were even more incredulous when the fishermen said it was a good deal and they were happy about it.*

I think the [word](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/incredible) you want is

> **incredible**
>   ADJECTIVE
>   **1** Impossible to believe.
>   *an almost incredible tale of triumph and tragedy*

or the informal use given

> **2.1** *informal* Very good; wonderful.
>   *I was mesmerized: she looked so incredible*

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to EL&U. It is grammatical but, in the vast majority of cases it is incorrect. [Incredulous](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/incredulous) is defined by the Oxford online dictionary as

> (of a person or their manner) unwilling or unable to believe something

so a *thing*, with the possible exception of an Artificial Intelligence, cannot be described as "incredulous". If you want to say that something is difficult or impossible to believe the word you need is [incredible](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/incredible) defined by the same dictionary as

> 1 Impossible to believe.
>
> 2 Difficult to believe; extraordinary.

or, informally

> Very good; wonderful.

If a person finds something difficult to believe then *they* are *incredulous* but that is because the *thing* they find difficult to believe is, for them, *incredible* in the first sense quoted above.